# Redux Toolkit Dispatch type intellisense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I followed redux toolkit typescript [doc](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript). The doc says to create own useDispatch hook given below

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

and use it in the components in the following way

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const increase = () => {
  dispatch(increase());
}
```

Everything works perfectly. But what I have expected dispatch should have IntelliSense of all the actions which is missing. My question is how I can achieve these types so that I will be able to get help from typescript which actions are allowed for dispatch argument.

on hovering dispatch function it is showing the types following

```
const dispatch: <AnyAction>(action: AnyAction) => AnyAction
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Redux, *any* action can be dispatched at any time. So, it doesn't make any sense conceptually to try to limit what actions can be dispatched at the type level.  There are a number of "Redux + TS" libs and articles out there that try to implement that approach, but we maintainers feel it's not useful.

See Redux maintainer Lenz Weber's post [Do Not Create Union Types with Redux Actions](https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union) for more details.

That said, I would at least expect that hovering over `useAppDispatch` would produce a TS type that looks more like this:

```
(alias) useAppDispatch(): ThunkDispatch<CombinedState<{
    // fill in actual state fields for your app here
}>, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>
import useAppDispatch
```

Double-check your app setup and make sure you're using RTK's `configureStore` for your store creation.

Comment: Thanks maekerikson. I understand your point. For the purpose of learning could you please share some links of the articles where it is implemented?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Can you clarify?

Comment: "There are a number of "Redux + TS" libs and articles out there that try to implement that approach" - I am just curious to learn these approaches, so I requested some articles.